# Does typesetting of mathematical content differ in right-to-left languages?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, convention

Languages such as Arabic or Hebrew are written [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left). Does the way mathematical content is written differ in those languages?

Some simple examples of which I would be interested to know how they are written in righ-to-left languages:

- $E = mc^2$: Is it eventually written as $c^2 m = E$?
- Do equations evolve like

\begin{align}
ax^2 + bx + c&=0\\
\frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} - b}{a \cdot 2} &= x_{1,2}\Leftrightarrow\\
... &= x_1\Leftrightarrow\\
\end{align}

- Is the $n$-th root written the same way or is it mirrored?
- Is $4-1=3$ or $4-1=-3$ or $4-1=3-$?

Are there other differences?

Comment: Taking a first glance at https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A9_%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9 it seems as if math would be used the same way everywhere. From left to right, top to bottom. However, at the bottom there is a mirrored root symbol.

Comment: http://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%3Dmc%C2%B2 also suggests that there is no change. EDIT: Apparently there is a difference in the pre-university Arab world: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Arabic_mathematical_notation

Comment: The reason why Wikipedia uses the western style math might simply be due to technical difficulties. Getting nice math rendered in another way might not be that easy.

Comment: Well, there's no "Hebrew math notation" as far as I can tell. Just Arabic. In any case, Asaf Karagila — with one of the highest reputations on the site — is Israeli, so see if you can get his attention.